# Login to an ethereum dapp on sending a transaction?

Tags: dapps, authentication

I'm trying to build a sample dapp. The login process in ethereum dapps usually involves signing a message from metamask to prove ownership of an account. Is there a way we could design login in such a way that the user gets logged in automatically when sending a transaction (invoking a state changing function). This is feasible since both operations require signing. Any ideas please ?

Comment: Can you implement login in DApp, which can work with both ways (1) singing message - no cost (2) sending transaction? little more example of Dapp logic please?

Comment: login in my dapp will only be required to provide a list of prior transactions performed by the user, or any other such user specific data. Also, like you mentioned, login should happen in either way. Either, user explicitly logs in by clicking on the login button on the top right and signing a message (like cryptokitties), or user can also login directly during sending a transaction.

Comment: Will this more simpler approach, to check if user is logged-in at metamask and get the wallet address directly and display all the user specific data or do user specific functions?

Comment: If the app shows data that is already in the blockchain what is the purpose of logging? knowing the address allows anyone to check all the activity of an address

Comment: @jaime if that were true then why do we need wallet dapps that showcase your transaction history? cant people just access it from the blockchain directly? ...

Comment: Yes they can access it directly, you do not need a wallet app to see the list of your previous transactions in the network, note that I can go to etherscan with any address and see all the activity of such account. Everything is public.

Comment: @Jaime, they can... doesn't mean they want to keep checking etherscan to know about their transactions. at the end of the day, even cryptokitties based transactions are also in etherscan, doesnt mean people should be made to manually check the transactions in etherscan to see all the ERC-721 tokens they bought... 
can we focus on the question at hand please ? ...

Comment: @Combo, you have missunderstood my point, if your app only shows data that is public, you can display the data without asking them to logging.

Comment: I understand your point @jaime, but you arent realizing that ALL data is public in blockchain, doesn't mean it is pointless to procure user-specific data after validation. for any dapp, a user needs access to all his/her recent and historical activities pertaining to that dapp in one place. simple as that.

Comment: @yogesh, its a question about UX. it becomes easier for a user to directly go for the transaction and then, in the next step, view the activity committed, plus all other historical activities. so a more 'streamlined approach' might be preferred over a simpler approach. any ideas ?

Comment: I think what @yogesh is saying is: just show the data for the current MetaMask address. There's no need to wait for a signature or a transaction to _prove_ the identity of the user. That's only necessary if you're going to store some secret data off-chain.

Comment: I understood that, but instead of focusing on the 'why', can we come to the 'how' ? I'd be using login for several purpose, to retain activity data, to also ask for email ID to store connected with address value, or to commit to handling any other confidential data. The specific detailed functionality of the dapp hasn't been decided but for broad strokes, I'd like to know what all is possible to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @All for helpful comments. How about this? To ease UX, we get metamask address.. and that would be tagged with the user account in DApp. So, you dapp knows who is logged and display correct user account session. So, you have to ask users to login to metamask (MM) if they want to login and your dapp can associate MM account with any user account... what do you guys think  of this?